# Mouse event with double click in java

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, double-click

By default `MouseClicked` event starts with one click. I have one in a `JTextPane` but I want to start with double click. Is it possible?

Comment: "Mouseclicked event starts with one click" makes no sense: mouseClicked events are dispatched whenever matching pressed/released are detected, for any number of clicks. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: yeah, I understand that, technically, but what's the problem? simply use @Johnny Rocket 's answer ...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I believe you can extract the click count from the MouseEvent (assuming its called e)

Try this

```
if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && !e.isConsumed()) {
     e.consume();
     //handle double click event.
}
```

Comment: Is there a good way to reset the click count so that the user can keep double-clicking and have every second click count as a double-click without a pause between?

Comment: @mouseas You could simply do if(e.getClickCount() % 2 == 0) to achieve that effect

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there will be a solution to this, since Java can run on non-pc devices.

Most portable devices don't support double-click.

You may keep track of the moment of each mouse click and fire your own "double-click" event. But I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: hmm .. where do you see mobile devices come into play?

Answer (score 3):

```
    private void jEditorPane3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

            if (evt.getClickCount() == 2 && !evt.isConsumed()) {
                    evt.consume();
                    System.out.println("Double Click");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the mousePressed() or mouseReleased() methods and asking if e.getClickCount() == 2 , I recommend using the mousePressed() or mouseReleased() instead of mouseClicked() method since using those will give the user more time to perform the clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the time lapsed between consecutive clicks. Compare it with a threshold value and decide yourself whether it is a double click or not.