# Swing Double click

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, listselectionlistener

When trying to select item from list by doubleclick it's selecting once for both List, but after selecting by single click!!!

```
    listScrollPanel.setViewportView(categoryList);
    subCategoryList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
        String[] strings = {"Sub-category 1", "Sub-category 2", "Sub-category 3", "Sub-category 4", "Sub-category 5", "Sub-category 6"};
    });
subCategoryList.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        infoBox(Integer.toString(evt.getClickCount()), subCategory);
        if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
            subCategoryList.addListSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                    subCategoryListValueChanged(evt);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
private void subCategoryListValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {

    subCategory = (String) subCategoryList.getSelectedValue();
    labelSC.setText(CAT_HEADER);
    listScrollPanel.setViewportView(categoryList);
}
private static void infoBox(String Message, String location) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Message, location, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

How to let him listen only double-click?
I have categoryList which after double-click and ListSelection changing viewportView to subCategory which works same! but they after first 2 double-click react on single-click!

Comment: !!! please why shouting, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about container with List,

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409347/mouse-event-with-double-click-in-java

Comment: Yeah i saw this question! And added in my code! but it didn't worked! so i asked! and here have been told, thet i must delete `addListSelectionListener`!!!
IF YOU can see, in my code is double click which was in question you throw! BUT IT didn't worked! I realy appreciate all of authors here and listen and respect, but yours.... it's like `something sort of like was`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding a new `ListSelectionListener` every time a double mouse click event occurs.  Each one of these will respond to single mouse clicks. You can just use a `MouseListener` on its own:

```
subCategoryList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
           String selectedValue = subCategoryList.getSelectedValue();
           // do stuff with selectedValue...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: to be precise: "*each and every time* a double mouse click occurs"

Comment: if i may ask here! what is difference between subCategoryList.getModel().getElementAt(subCategoryList.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint())); and subCategoryList.getSelectedValue(); ???

Comment: Both are equivalent, `getSelectedValue` is shorter so have updated with this