# double click on node on JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I search for my problem in this forum and i found this source code but i found the same problem

To explain more, I have `JTree` I implement `TreeSelectionListener` in my class and in `valuechanged` i put this code my it works but the problem when i do double click on node it counts the clicks that i did  and displays the results several times

here is the code

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    int selRow = arbre.getRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
    TreePath selPath = arbre.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if(selRow != -1) {
        if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
            System.out.println("one click");
        }
        else if(e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            System.out.println("double click");
        }
    }
}
};
arbre.addMouseListener(ml);
```

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8409363/300257

Comment: Try changing `public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {` to `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {`.  If that does not work to your need, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).