# javafx different actions on one button

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am making a blackjack game and was wondering if I could make it so that I had two different actions on a single button.

This is what I have so far on the hit button, but instead of having the second card show on a double click, I want it to show the second card when you press the button again.

```
    public void hit(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 1) {
            card5 = deck.dealCard();
            pcard3.setImage(card5.getImage());
        } 
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
            card6 = deck.dealCard();
            pcard4.setImage(card6.getImage());
        } 
}
```

Comment: this sounds like you need a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) - otherwise you will be forced to count, save and restore things; and thats quite tedious once your application grows to a certain size

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409347/mouse-event-with-double-click-in-java . Other alternatives: open a menu with click, or use right-click.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an iterator whose value can be increased on each click. And for different values set different functionalities. See the code

```
int i =0; 
public void hit(MouseEvent event) {
        if (i%2== 0) {
            card5 = deck.dealCard();
            pcard3.setImage(card5.getImage());
        } else if (i%2 == 1) {
            card6 = deck.dealCard();
            pcard4.setImage(card6.getImage());
        } 
i++;
}
```

Comment: card5 will be started on any attempt to start card6

Comment: @OferYuval  Its working absolutely fine for me. Both cards are started separately on alternative mouse click. User may change the `if` condition based on the no. of times he wants to show that particular functionality. I think that's what user wants.